# Extract data from json file python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

[image: Screenshot Console]

How can I get all the data in my image database into the database ?

My code :

```
import re
import json
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print ("Opened database successfully");
with open('tem.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)
     for p in data:
         data[p] = re.sub("<[^>]+>", "", str(data[p]))
         print("%s: %s" % (p, data[p]))
```

I use SQLite:

[image: Screenshot SQLite Browser]

Comment: Whats is your issue?

Comment: I want to load all data in json file into db

Comment: you can use Pandas , It has  pd.read_json  you can use it to read data and then directly write it in the DB. sqlite3 supports pandas really well.

Comment: Can u show me ? andy

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to read the Json and create a dataframe and then write it into the DB
I have added a sample code.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json ('path\data.json')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my.db', echo=False)

df.to_sql('mytable', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

The advantage of this is that with pandas you can make changes in the data very easily.